# Logging AWS ElasticTranscoder Job statuses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-elastic-transcoder, amazon-cloudtrail

I have an AWS ElasticTranscoder setup which upon receiving jobs, produces status event messages for each job ('Progressing', 'Error', 'Warning' etc) to SNS. The SNS is hooked to a SQS queue which is consumed by my consumer service.

I want to log the status of the jobs i.e. when a job errors out, I want the event message sent by ElasticTranscoder to be logged. Is there a way of doing this using Cloudtrail? Or should it happen on my consumer's side  when it consumes the messages?